# How to iterate time travel query in snowflake over every hour of day of a month?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

like my main query is like

`SELECT TABLE_NAME,LAST_MODIFIED_UTC FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE AT(TIMESTAMP => '2023-12-23 00.00.00' :: TIMESTAMP) WHERE <condition>`

I want this to iterate for every hour of every day say for month of December 2023
or for any given month of an given year? Is this possible?

I have tried creating date dimension table to regenerate a calendar with its timestamp, but throwing me an error like *AT needs a constant timestamp*

`SELECT TABLE_NAME,LAST_MODIFIED_UTC FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE AT(TIMESTAMP => (select some_datetimestamp from date_dimension_table) :: TIMESTAMP) WHERE <condition>`

I dont know how to iterate this using pure SQL, I cannot use python as its restricted in our environment, so if there a pure SQL solution that can be directly run on Snowflake UI, that will be great.

I need output like csv

```
TABLE_NAME,LAST_MODIFIED_UTC
ABC,'2023-12-23 00:00:00'
ABC,'2023-12-23 01:00:00'
ABC,'2023-12-23 02:00:00'
GHJ,'2023-12-23 05:00:00'
ERT,'2023-12-23 07:00:00'
```

Comment: You’d have to use dynamic SQL to generate each statement and then execute it. You can do this using SQL Scripting in the UI or using any of the supported languages in a stored proc

Comment: Can you join with the timestamp table?

Comment: @Schwern no, you can’t. This “AT TIMESTAMP” syntax is Snowflake-specific